# What is the solution for Lenovo after BIOS update failure?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, thinkpad

I have Lenovo T500 and I tried to update BIOS and the update made my PC hang and stop working.
Is there a way to restore my Lenovo or fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.. never had an error like this, but it seems you are not the only one. (Shame on Lenovo..seriously.)

First, try this "sequence":
http://lnv.lithium.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/My-T400-Hangs-a-the-boot-stage/m-p/188475#M19620

Then there is a thread:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T500-BIOS-flash-failed/td-p/222074/page/2

(But you should simply just go to the service and have them fix it in warranty. All T500 comes with 3yr warranty, all of them should be still in warranty.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could live boot from something like [Hirens Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) or [Ultimate Boot CD](http://wiki.ultimatebootcd.com/index.php?title=Tools)

Both include a set of BIOS tools which you may be able to use to reinstall the old BIOS or try and install the new BIOS again.

Alternatively the warranty or a repair shop are good choices if you feel uncomfortable trying these tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, disabling McAfee anti-virus solved it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?